# Share via WhatsApp only if it is installed

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I'm trying to make a WhatsApp share option (for a mobile website) available to visitors that have the app installed.

What would be the best way to verify that the visitor is able to use this feature so I can enable/disable it accordingly?

The feature would just be a link using the custom URL scheme:

`<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>`

Comment: could you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 10):

You can solve this by checking whether the link will open or not.

Here is my code

```js
function open_whatsapp(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'HEAD',
      url: 'whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!',
      success: function() {
        window.location='whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!';   
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Whatsapp not installed");
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="share_whatsapp" onclick="open_whatsapp()">Share with Whatsapp</button>
```

Comment: I get the following error each time I execute open_whatsapp(): "Failed to load whatsapp://send?phone=+XXX: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Answer (score 0):

It is not good solution, because it depends on OS.

```
if(isMobile()){
   function onWhatsAppClick(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       window.location='whatsapp://send?text=text=Hello%20World!';
   }
}
```

Explain:

1. You should check and show *WhatsApp* on mobile only.
2. Prevent default, and open the link with *window.location*

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/U4CtbxeA81d25lc7dlGe?p=preview