# Detect if WhatsApp is installed

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

Using Android or a desktop browser, please visit this [WhatsApp test page](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62852226667755&text=test) and click the `Send` button. If WhatsApp is not installed it will show you a message.

How does the code detection on that page work? I tried the following but nothing happens.

```js
try {
  location.href = 'whatsapp://send/?phone=62812345678&text=test';
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: `Linking`? how the code in plain JS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321472/share-via-whatsapp-only-if-it-is-installed

Comment: `How the code detection on that page work?` - you can look at the client-side code yourself using dev tools (F12 key) in Google Chrome desktop.  The network tab will show all code added to the page.

Comment: @jpthesolver2 thanks, but it not work `blocked by CORS policy`

Comment: @DaveS as I wrote above The network tab only tell me it open `whatsapp://...` the javascript is very large and minified/unreadable I can't find where the code for the listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here my testing on Android:

- `Built-in Browser (Webview) and Firefox` if WA installed You can use `iframe` to auto open WhatsApp
- `Chrome and Opera` Need user click action

and this simple code to check if WhatsApp are installed

```js
let clickTimeout;
document.querySelector('#openWA').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let start = Date.now();
  clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    if (Date.now() - start > 1250)
      return;
    alert('WA not installed')
  }, 1e3);

  // reset the setTimeout or the alert will always be fired
  window.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    clearTimeout(clickTimeout)
  });
})
```

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send/?phone=62812345678&amp;text=test" id="openWA">Send to WhatsApp</button>

<!-- Auto open on WebView and Firefox -->
<iframe id="launcher" src="whatsapp://send/?phone=62812345678&amp;text=test" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the page, it appears that at least on Chrome, they programmatically open an iframe with the src of `whatsapp://send/?phone=<number>&text=test`. They then start a 1000ms timeout after which the "Looks like you don't have WhatsApp installed!" text is shown. This timeout is cancelled by an `blur` event handler, meaning that their check is based on your device opening WhatsApp when that URL is loaded, which blurs the window.

The function which triggers after the timeout also seems to check if the timeout took longer than 1250ms. I suspect that this handles the case where your phone's browser stops executing JS timers when it changes apps.

On IE, they use [`window.navigator.msLaunchUri`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msLaunchUri), which accepts a `noHandlerCallback`.

See for yourself by opening your browser's devtools and searching for `WhatsAppApiOpenUrl`. On Chrome, the Search can be found from the devtools' menu:

[image: screenshot of where the Search tool can be found in Chrome's devtools]

Here's some example code.

```
const detectWhatsapp = (phone, text) => {
  const uri = `whatsapp://send/?phone=${encodeURIComponent(
    phone
  )}&text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`;

  const onIE = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      window.navigator.msLaunchUri(
        uri,
        () => resolve(true),
        () => resolve(false)
      );
    });
  };

  const notOnIE = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const a =
        document.getElementById("wapp-launcher") || document.createElement("a");
      a.id = "wapp-launcher";
      a.href = uri;
      a.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(a);

      const start = Date.now();
      const timeoutToken = setTimeout(() => {
        if (Date.now() - start > 1250) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      }, 1000);

      const handleBlur = () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutToken);
        resolve(true);
      };
      window.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur);

      a.click();
    });
  };

  return window.navigator.msLaunchUri ? onIE() : notOnIE();
};
```

Please note that it adds an event listener each time it's called. If you're rolling this out into production, please use `window.removeEventListener` to remove `handleBlur` after the promise resolves. It also appends a DOM node into the body, if that matters to you.

Usage example:

```
detectWhatsapp('<your number here>', 'test').then(hasWhatsapp =>
  alert(
     'You ' + 
        (hasWhatsapp ? 'have WhatsApp' : "don't have WhatsApp")
  )
)
```

Comment: would love to see a general example with snippet (:

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Comment: @A.Meshu I've edited my post with an example, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work on mobile in CodeSandbox. Please give it a go and see if it works for you locally! I was able to get the link working with `<a>`, so perhaps you could do the same trick with an anchor tag and `.click()`.

Comment: @A.Meshu I managed to get it working for myself with the anchor element trick. I added it to my answer.

Comment: @cubbrr I Checked the first edit and it works! Nice job!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery, bassed on the code above if whats app does not open open a new page using whatsapp web instead of iframe launcher:

```
$('a[href^="whatsapp://send?"]').click(function() {
    var button = this,
     f = Date.now(),
    j = setTimeout(function() {
        if (Date.now() - f > 1025){
            return;
        }else{
            var newLink = button.getAttribute('href').replace("whatsapp://send?", "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?");
            button.setAttribute('href', newLink); 
            button.setAttribute('target', "_blank"); 
            $(button).closest('div').append('<a class="hide new" href="' + newLink + '" target="_blank" ></a>');
            $(button).closest('div').find('a.new')[0].click();
        }
    }, 1e3);        

})
```